# Reference request: Proof of the S-unit theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

One form of the S-unit theorem is the following:

Let $S$ be a finite set of primes. A rational S-unit is a rational number $a/b$ such that all prime divisors of both $a$ and $b$ belong to the set $S$. Then the equation $x+y=1$ has only finitely many solutions in the set of S-units.

What are some good references for a proof of this? I am also interested in generalizations as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are only talking about reduced fractions, since if $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=1$, then $\frac{ap^n}{bp^n}+\frac{c}{d}=1$ for any prime in $S$, giving you infinite solutions.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim, Yes, because $\frac{ap^n}{bp^n} = \frac{a}{b}$ are in the same equivalence class.

Comment: See Izquierdo, L’équation aux S-unités. Voyage géométrique en théorie des nombres

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this question. Anyhow, there's also a recent book by Evertse and Györy on unit equations: https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/ This is, however, a little bit more advanced than the French book, which was written up by students after a seminar.

Answer (score 1):

Lang's "Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry", chapter 8.

Comment: can you add more details?

Comment: It's theorem 3.1 therein, what is there more to say?